# Stop an absolute div overflowing a parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create some interactive spots on my website when a user rolls over the hotspot, I want the popup to be full width. relative to the container `.hotspot-wrp`. Currently, the popup flows outside of the viewable area and on mobile the content isn't viewable.

```css
.hotspot-wrp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #636e72;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.hot-spot {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(227, 193, 122, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 350ms;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #E8C378;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.hot-spot:hover .tooltip,
.hot-spot:active .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot-wrp">
  <div class="hot-spot" style="top:43.8776%; left:4.4476%;">
    <div class="tooltip">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Some demo text will be in here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hot-spot" style="top:4.0816%; left:63.4146%;">
    <div class="tooltip">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Some demo text will be in here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/L7ksfdmc/

Comment: If your allowed to use javascript, then thats how I would solve this. Measure the `hotspot-wrp` and set the `tooltip`'s width to the width of the `hotspot-wrp`. But you would need to take into consideration the position of the `hot-spot` and minus the remaining amount of how far it is from the edge of the  `hotspot-wrp` (top, right, bottom or left) that will prevent you from overflowing the `tooltip`. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent container.

```css
.hotspot-wrp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #636e72;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hot-spot {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(227, 193, 122, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease 350ms;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #E8C378;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.hot-spot:hover .tooltip,
.hot-spot:active .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot-wrp">
  <div class="hot-spot" style="top:43.8776%; left:4.4476%;">
    <div class="tooltip">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Some demo text will be in here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hot-spot" style="top:4.0816%; left:63.4146%;">
    <div class="tooltip">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Some demo text will be in here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow hidden clips any child content and doesn't stop an absolute child from overflowing the parent. If the child has a fixed width or a width too large the div still over flows and the content is clipped.

Comment: @SamXronn What do you expect it to do? Scrollbars? Re-scaling the child to accommodate the content?

Comment: I expect the child to respect that the parent has a relative positioning so that a child div with position absolute, when positioned to the, left the child to sit against the parent on the left, and doesn't overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Just as Emil said use `overflow:hidden` and for making your tooltip full width, choose the required length in pixels to increase the width. If you use `width:100%` in .tootltip css, it will only acquire the width of its parent div's width. So use absolute length as per requirement or length of text inside tooltip.